# How to get MySQL's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in PHP - CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, timestamp

I'm looking for a way to get the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returned from MySQL, and ultimately, I want to construct a `DateTime($with_the_result);` in PHP (CodeIgniter), and compare it with a MySQL timestamp, using the function in [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637897/getting-exact-time-difference-from-mysql-datetime-field). (Of course, changing the 3rd line)

I don't want to use PHP's `DateTime();` to initialize it because my PHP server (Apache?) always have the wrong values. Although MySQL could be wrong too, I just want consistency. So I want to make sure that I get `'NOW()'` in PHP

How can I do that with CodeIgniter & MySQL (and maybe Active Record? not necesssarily).

I will also appreciate any comments about the difference between timestamp and datetime, and which one should I use for big databases. I just need precision up to seconds.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: It's going to be based on the time value on your server, so unless your MySQL server is separate from the server where your PHP is running, it's probably not going to matter. Seems like understanding the time on the server is going to be a lot easier to deal with and more performant than querying the database just to get the time...

Comment: Seems legit. But in my local WAMPServer, MySQL always has the correct value, but PHP has a difference. More strangely, the difference is not a (multiple of an) hour but like 30-40 minutes.. I found the answer to my question, but your comment made me think that I might be asking the wrong question :) So if I understood you correctly, you are saying that both PHP and MySQL gets the time from the same source -whics is probably Apache- right? So it (my local installation) adds an offset to the PHP I guess.

Comment: MySQL and PHP are only going to have access to local resources, so yes, they are not making any sort of call out to a time service. If MySQL is always correct and PHP is always wrong in your WAMP environment and they are on the same machine...that would strike me as very odd. I'm not horribly familiar with WAMP, but the time would be the system time, which apache also uses

Comment: I now tested with time(); and there is a 2-hour difference. PHP is 2 hours to the west.

Comment: I would suggest looking at your configurations for mysql and php and making sure the timezones are set and the same values. That's the only thing I can think of that would cause a discrepancy like that on the same machine...hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can do this :

```
echo $this->db->query("SELECT NOW();")->row_array()['NOW()'];
```

which prints the timestamp : `2014-01-25 20:22:34`

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is the number of seconds passed since 1970, and date time is pretty much the date and time down to the second.

If you're trying to get the current timestamp I'd suggest using

```
$current_timestamp = time();
```

In PHP it will return the current timestamp whenever it is ran. You would then just subtract the timestamp from MySQL with the `$current_timestamp`;

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is exactly this. time(); returns the time 2 hours earlier. i.e., my local time is 20:41 but it says 18:41.

Comment: Here's a link on how to change the timezone in PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php . It changes the timezone for all time related functions, and if that doesn't work, but it should, you could always add 7200 ( the equivalent of two hours ) to make up for it.